# How can I get pytesseract to adjust its targeting parameters in real time depending on where my data has shifted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract to read data from a web page. However, it's not always in the same exact place. Sometimes, I end up on an application where data has shifted to the left or right a little bit, because there's lack of information on the application or because one of the cells contains too much information.

Here's a sample image:

[image]

Here, I'm trying to read and print the first line containing the text Brazil(BZ) (and eventually, I'll have it read the other two lines as well). However, this information is again, scattered. So, I'm currently targeting it like this:

```
import pytesseract
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import configparser
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = os.path.join(os.environ['ProgramFiles'], 'Tesseract-OCR', 'tesseract.exe')


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')


l1 = config['info']['l1']
l2 = config['info']['l2']
l3 = config['info']['l3']
l4 = config['info']['l4']

x1, y1 = int(l1), int(l2)
x2, y2 = int(l3), int(l4)

try:
    screenshot = np.array(pyautogui.screenshot())
    cropped_image1 = screenshot[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    gray_image1 = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray_image1)

    print(text1)

except:
    pass
```

my config.ini file has the following:

```
l1 = 189
l2 = 1038
l3 = 537
l4 = 1115
```

This is the area on the page I'm targeting, and it's failing to target the correct area on some applications. Is there a way to maybe search for the text "Country" then go down a little bit, and print whatever is below it, regardless of where it is on my screen?

Would I perhaps do better with selenium? I don't know if it can read html data from web pages in real time AFTER I process an application and end up on a different part of the site. Can it do that?

I tried targeting my data of interest but it fails because information is shifting depending on what information an applicant put in their application.